# "A is important in B, which C dominates", then C dominates A or C dominates B?

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence, `X` dominates `understanding of text` or `recommendation`?

> Precise understanding of text is critical in recommendation, which X dominates.

Comment: The nonrestrictive clause _which X dominates_ has as its antecedent _recommendation_ (hence the comma).

Comment: *which* (like other relative pronouns) normally stands for the immediately preceding noun.

Comment: Thank you, I got it.

Comment: Why not give an answer instead?